# How can I transform the the values from a column according to the index of a vector?

Tags: r, apply

I have a vector `courses`:

```
courses <- c("Math","English","Sport","Physik", "Chemie")

# > courses
[1] "Math"    "English" "Sport"   "Physik"  "Chemie"
```

I have a data frame `enrollment`:

```
enrollment <- data.frame(course=c("Sport", "Physik", "Sport", "English", "English", "Math", "Chemie", "Math"))

> enrollment
   course
1   Sport
2  Physik
3   Sport
4 English
5 English
6    Math
7  Chemie
8    Math
```

What I want to do is turn the value in column course from `enrollment` into the course_id from the index of the `course`:

```
> enrollment
  couse_id
1        3
2        4
3        3
4        2
5        2
6        1
7        5
8        1
```

How can I do it efficiently?

If I want to use `which()` to get the course index and use `apply()` to apply it on the `enrollment`, how can I write the code?

Comment: `as.numeric(factor(enrollment$course, levels=courses))` or `match(enrollment$course, courses)` which iha clearer intent to me, but i would think less efficient

Comment: @user20650 - post 'em up!  `fastmatch::fmatch` can also be used for faster matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of approaches

```
as.numeric(factor(enrollment$course, levels=courses))
```

where the `levels` argument ensures that the values are ordered as intended

or

```
match(enrollment$course, courses)
```

which returns the index position of each `enrollment$course` within `courses`

And for a faster match - from RichardScriven

```
fastmatch::fmatch(enrollment$course, courses)
```